# TKINTER: I can't copy a string output

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a simple GUI application that returns a string after taking a user input. I want to be able to copy the string once it's printed on the GUI but I can't, I think it's because initally I used Label:

```
d = 'some string that I want to copy'
data = Label(main, text=d)
data.pack()
```

I tried doing Text instead so that I can copy the output from a text box but I keep getting this error message:

**bad wrap "some string that I want to copy" must be char, none, or word.**

code:

```
data = Text(main, wrap=d)
data.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wrap` option takes one of the following three strings: `word`, `none`, or `char`.  You're passing something else.

If your goal is to insert the value of `d` in a text widget, you must use the `insert` method after creating the widget:

```
data = Text(main, wrap="word")
data.insert("end", d)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, bad wrap "some string that I want to copy" must be char, none, or word.

Comment: @sjoelly take a look, he set `wrap='word'`. Dont change `'word'` from there to `"some string that I want to copy"`, means just copy paste this.

Comment: @sjoelly: you cannot possibly get that error with my code. It is impossible. You must have copied it wrong. My code is literally passing "word" to the `wrap` option. If your error says you aren't passing "word", then you aren't passing "word".

Comment: Hi, @CoolCloud was right, I thought I had to change 'word'. It works, thank you!

Comment: @BryanOakley, do you know how I can print everything in one text box?  My function loops, so every time it prints something in a new text box and the boxes are too big.

Comment: @sjoelly: You can create the text widget once, and then you can call the `insert` method as often as you like once it has been created.

Comment: @BryanOakley it creates a new text box for each iteration, I would just like everything to be appended to the same text box :o

Comment: @sjoelly: like I said: create the text box once, and then call `insert` in each iteration.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @BryanOakley! I just needed to have data = Text(main,wrap='word') before the loop starts. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This works?

```
from tkinter import  *
main = Tk()

d='This is the input'

data = Label(main, text=d)
data.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

All though it would help if you posted your full code